# Dystopian police story set in a future Kansas

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Dystopian short story. Maybe written in the late 80s or early 90s.

The United States have broken up. I want to say corporations run/own at least some of the states. This story is set in the Kansas Territory or the Incorporated Territory of Kansas. The story focuses on a cop. (this is not *Code Three*) I think he works for the Kansas State Police, but they are now a private force. Everything has been privatized, I believe. I have no memory of the actual story. Just this set-up.

I am pretty sure there were some *Road Warrior*-like chase scenes, but the political and economic concepts were what stayed with me.

Comment: Please tell us everything you remember about the story. Is the cop a man or a woman? Is the technology advanced, primitive, or about the same as today? Does the cop travel on foot, on horseback, by motorcycle, car, helicopter, airplane? Is he armed with a pistol, raygun, phaser, sword? Why don't you tell us about the "political and economic concepts" that stayed with you?

Comment: Something by [James Gunn](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1162), perhaps? Gunn is from Kansas, and has set some of his stories there.

Comment: Law enforcement in Kansas makes me think of Lee Killough's Brilll and Maxwell series.

Answer (score 10):

That sounds like it might be Vernor Vinge's ["The Ungoverned"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ungoverned).  [Here's the text.](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/1416520724/1416520724___4.htm)  It's set in his Bobble universe years after *The Peace War* when a radical libertariansm has taken root and Kansas -- like most of the world -- is entirely ungoverned and things like policing and defense are for hire (companies like "Al's Protection Racket" or "Michigan State Police") or do-it-yourself. The Republic of New Mexico is one of the few governments left and thinks to invade the supposedly undefended Kansas.  (After a seemingly unstoppable rampage across Kansas, the invasion is halted by one especially well-armed Kansas farmer.)  W. W. Brierson (the main character in *Marooned in Real Time* is a major character and as I recall, he's chased at one point by the USNM forces.

Comment: This does sound a lot like The Ungoverned - though he wouldn't consider it a dystopia!